# How to show Data in UITableView ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uitableview

Developing a iPAD app, where I'm trying to populate table, This is how i'm doing:
In view did load, I'm creating two dictionary object and adding object as Pdf and Excel.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

arrDocuments = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSArray *arr1 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"PDF", nil];
NSDictionary *pdf = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:arr1 forKeys:nil];
NSArray *arr2 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Excel", nil];
NSDictionary *excel = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:arr2 forKeys:nil];
[arrDocuments addObject:pdf];
[arrDocuments addObject:excel];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

  return [arrDocuments count]; 

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

// Return the number of rows in the section.
//return [arrReceipes count];
NSDictionary *dictionary = [arrDocuments objectAtIndex:section];
NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:[self.sortedKeys objectAtIndex:section]];
return [array count];

}

-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
UITableView *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
if (cell ==nil) {
   cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
}

return cell;
}
```

With this implementation I'm not able to see table view.Its going to main method and showing me **SIGABRT** message.Where I'm going wrong??

Comment: in cellForRowAtIndexPath add: cell.textLabel.text = ...

Comment: Where did you actually create the table view?

Comment: @llario, The intellisence is not showing "cell.textLable.text",When I'm writing this, its showing textLable is not identified..

Comment: post any NSLog in method and check where the app crashes..

Comment: what is this self.sortedkeys ?

Answer (score 0):

While creating `NSDictionary`, you have passed nil in place of keys array,

```
 NSDictionary *pdf = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:arr1 forKeys:nil];
```

You should give proper objects and keys to the dictionary. This method expects objects and keys to be given in an array as you can see in its method signature.

```
+ (instancetype)dictionaryWithObjects:(NSArray *)objects forKeys:(NSArray *)keys
```